# Select timestamp from Bigquery without converting it to a string or human-readable date

Tags: google-bigquery

This should be extremely easy but nothing on google, chatgpt, or anywhere I've looked or tried has worked.

I simply want to select the raw integer value of the epoch milliseconds of a timestamp column without any human-readable format. to demonstrate, if you just select current tiemstamp you get a human-readable date.

SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();

```
[{
  "f0_": "2023-06-27 04:15:05.576164 UTC"
}]
```

I want:

```
[{
    "f0_": 12301235701273
}]
```

I'm not passing the timestamp into any time formatter. It's just doing it for me without asking.

Comment: see [unix_millis](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#unix_millis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @jaytiger, you can get the epoch timestamp by using Bigquery's  timestamp function UNIX_MILLIS().

For you case you can use:

```
SELECT UNIX_MILLIS (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) as millis
```

for which the output would be:

[image]